# Integer intervals with a summation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, integers

I'm struggling to understand this question that was posed in a lecture.
What is the value of the following sum of cardinalities?
$\sum_{n=0}^{10} |[5i..(5i+3)]|$

I originally thought I would do the summation of 5i, which is 275 and then the summation of 5i+3 which is 308.  I subtract the these and add 1, and get 34. But the answer is 44. And it has 4 unique elements.

Would appreciate an explanation for the process for obtaining this answer.
Thank you

Comment: I'm assuming that$$[5i\dots(5i+3)]=\{5i,5i+1,5i+2,5i+3\}$$and hence always has a cardinality of $4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $$[5i, 5i + 3] = \{5i, 5i+1, 5i +2, 5i+3\}$$ for $i \in [0,10]$:

Note that the above given set representation for $[5i, 5i+3]$ has 4 elements for each $i\in [0,10]$. Also, there are $11$ possible values of $i$.

So, the answer is $44$. *Note* that it's quite easy to check that there are no common elements between $[5i, 5i +3]$ and $[5j, 5j+3]$ for $i \neq j$.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, Rohan! I'm curious why are there 4 elements in this? I'm wondering, especially why you would have 5i+1, 5i+2, 5i+3?